# How to get keys, values from Java Maps(Multilevel Associative Array)

Tags: java

I have following array(Maps):

```
Map<String, String[]> fields = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
fields.put( "memberDOB", new String[]{ "true", "", "", "2", "date"} );
fields.put( "memberDOJ", new String[]{ "true", "", "", "2", "date"} );
fields.put( "membershipDate", new String[]{ "true", "", "", "2", "date"} );
fields.put( "txtAccountNo", new String[]{ "true", "1", "10", "1", "int"} );
fields.put( "txtMemIntro1Address", new String[]{ "true", "5", "", "1", "string"} );

   validate validateF = new validate();
      if(validateF.validate_fields(fields)){
          //validated
      }
```

Retrieving values and keys:

```
public boolean validate_fields(Map<String, String[]> fields) {
       //How to loop through each key
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to either Swing or your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
    // key iterate over all keys in fields
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator iterator=fields.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.next();
  // logic here
}
```

Also you can iterate on value and key both like following way

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
        + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: small correction Map.Entry<String, String[]>

Answer (score 1):

Java has for each iteration since 1.5,
so you can loop each key like this:

```
    for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
        String[] value = fields.get(key);
        // process the value
    }
```